# Can I directly edit string resources in an xml document when making android apps?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to learn android programming.

Following the tutorial at [Android Dev Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)

And I've created an app that launches a new activity.

Anywho, this launches and all that.
`
   public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE ="com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    public static int counterNumber=0;

```
public void thishappens(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessage.class);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = textView.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);`
```

the above launches the new activity displayMessage.class, a snippet is down below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    //layout refresh
    setContentView(textView);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
}
```

My problem is with the bottom two lines.   I can either load my layout or the text view created in the code.

so my question is, can I directly edit the string resources from the xml file?

I'd like to have the string that i did load directly into the activity_display_message layout.

Im not sure how.

How do I have a user enter input and have it transfer over to the next activity, while still keeping the layout i designed for that activity?

Comment: That isn't really how you do it. Just remove the second setContentViews. The views will (what you call refresh) themselves. setContentView tells your Activity what view you want to load into the view initially. After that all you have to do is modify them as you need to. No refresh necessary (unless you have an adapter, then you refresh the adapter not the view).

Comment: @zgc7009 maybe you're misunderstanding.  Im sorry.  Can I edit a string resource, housed in the strings.xml, from the java code and then have it transfer into the new display?

Comment: Ohhhhh... no you cant, sorry I misunderstood :P

Answer (score 3):

> so my question is, can I directly edit the string resources from the xml file?

No, you can't change `resources` at runtime. But your code seems kind of goofy. This is all going to run when the `Activity` starts up. So, you can check the message then just set it in your `TextView` of the layout.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    TextView textView (textView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    textView.setText(message);
}
```

simply create a `TextView` inside of `activity_display_message.xml` (here called `textView`) then set the text with the `message` variable.

Also, it is often a good idea to do some error checking such as

```
if (intent !== null && intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE != null)
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

or however you want to go about that.

### Storing...

You could store that value in a persistent value such as `SharedPreferences`, a file, db, etc... if you are wanting to use it later.

You can read more about that [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to refresh your views like this. Fortunately, Android will handle dynamically displaying the modifications that you make to a layout/view once it is set as your activity's view. However, you can do what you are trying to do ; that is, `passing your String as an extra in your Intent and setting the text of your dynamically added TextView to that String, then finally adding that view to your activity's content view.`

Since you want to add the TextView to your layout, just do this in place of your setContentViews (below refresh views comment).

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.activity_display_message);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText(message);
tv.setTextSize(40);
layout.addView(tv);
```

That will modify your layout view, adding your new TextView with the message as it's text to your layout.

Comment: How would I have input from the user load into the second layout without replacing the entire thing?

Comment: What packages do i have to import to get this to work? Thanks for your help @zgc7009

Comment: @christopherbaldwin It doesn't, you can't do it that way. You pass variables in intent's bundled extras or you store it somewhere using something like a shared pref.

Comment: Man im confused.  Where'd you learn this? do you have any suggestions for tutorials besides google?  Im a little lost.

Comment: also my question was about the LayoutParams   They show up as compiler errors in android studio

Comment: @christopherbaldwin There is a lot to learn, it takes time. The Google tutorials really do a pretty good job. Try finding a tutorial app that looks similar to what you are trying to accomplish and don't be afraid do look at the sample code Google has available with the sdk