# Inserting java variables into xml in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

So I've created a java class that generates a string that I would like to display in an XML GridLayout TextView, but I've been having trouble figuring out how to transfer the variable I've created in my java class into a usable format in XML.

I've tried simply creating a TextView in Java but I'm trying to create a vertical design with text directly over a button and GridLayout seems like the best way to do that.

Here's what my code boils down to

```
String output;

//determine value of string
```

And here's my XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.reid.agerangecalculator.CalculateActivity">

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text= ""/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</GridLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem and how you are trying to insert it isn't very clear. You get a reference to the `TextView`...`TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);` in Java then you set the text with `tv.setText(output);` after you initialize the `String`. Maybe explain "into a usable format in XML". You don't put it in your xml...that can't be changed. You set it in Java.

Comment: @VaibhavMule this question isn't IDE dependent. Shame on those who approved it

Comment: codeMagic is right! The main idea for using XML is for define the structure and then modify its contents programatically.

Comment: `resources` can't be changed after they are compiled. You can see this answer of mine for a little more information on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616759/can-i-directly-edit-string-resources-in-an-xml-document-when-making-android-apps/26616859#26616859